# Use of list of objects in python

Tags: python, list, object

I want to create a method that returns a list that contents instances of the class of an instance passed as a parameter for reference. Every element in the list (an instance) has an attribute (instance variable) that is a dictionary, and its content must be different for each one, the problem is that, even when the instance is created properly with the right content in its dictionary, when they are appended to the list to be returned, all the dictionaries (attrs) of the instances in the list get the same content.

This is the code

```
class ModelManager():
def get_subset(self, entity_class, condition_string, persistant):
    entity_subset=[]
    entity_attrs={}
    entity_attrs_list=[]
    attrs_list=[]
    record_list=persistant.get_subset(entity_class, condition_string, persistant)

    i=0
    for record in record_list:
        if i==0:
            for data in record:
                attrs_list.append(data)
        elif i>1:
            j=0
            for data in record:
                entity_attrs[attrs_list[j]]=data
                j=j+1
            new_instance=entity_class.clone()
            new_instance.set_attrs(entity_attrs)
            entity_subset.append(new_instance)
            print(new_instance.attrs)           #first print
        i=i+1

    for entity in entity_subset:
        print(entity.attrs)                     #second print
    return(entity_subset)

class Company(Entity):
def clone(self):
    company=Company()
    return company

class Entity:
def __init__(self):
    self.attrs={}

def set_attrs(self, attrs):
    self.attrs=attrs
```

And this is the result.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:oop01 hvillalobos$ virtual/bin/python3 oop01.py
{'id': '1', 'razon_social': 'Attractora S.A. de C.V.', 'rfc': 'xxxxxxxx'}
{'id': '2', 'razon_social': 'Otra empresa sa de cv', 'rfc': ' yyyyyyyy'}
{'id': '3', 'razon_social': 'Una mas sa de vc', 'rfc': ' zzzzz'}

{'id': '3', 'razon_social': 'Una mas sa de vc', 'rfc': ' zzzzz'}
{'id': '3', 'razon_social': 'Una mas sa de vc', 'rfc': ' zzzzz'}
{'id': '3', 'razon_social': 'Una mas sa de vc', 'rfc': ' zzzzz'}
```

Do any body knows why all the elements in the list have the same content at the end?
Thank you all

Comment: `self.attrs=attrs` doesn't copy data. All your instances are using the same `attrs` dict, because you called `set_attrs` with the same dict for each instance. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `self.attrs = attrs.copy()` might help

Comment: Any change to any mutable object reference, will change all its references.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really fast and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work the way you want because you're reusing the same dictionary for all of your instances. Because you keep modifying that dictionary's contents, the end result is that all of the instances you create have the data that should belong in the last one.

You can fix this issue in a few ways. The simplest way would be to just move the creation of the dictionary into your loop. Another option would be to assign a copy of the dictionary to each instance after you've created it. But I think the most elegant solution is to change your code for filling the dictionary with data so that you create a fresh dictionary at the same time.

Try replacing this code:

```
j=0
for data in record:
    entity_attrs[attrs_list[j]]=data
    j=j+1
```

with:

```
entity_attrs = dict(zip(attrs_list, record))
```